# PyCharm switches between thin and normal font when I move caret

Tags: pycharm

This behavior started with me updating to PyCharm 2019.1 from 2018.3. For some reason the fonts are all very thin and crispy, which they weren't before, until I move the caret into the vicinity of the affected text, at which point the font becomes normal.

Any ideas what might be causing this? I use the Material Theme UI plugin, if that matters.

[image: Very thin font]

[image: Normal font]

Comment: I 'm running Pycharm 2019.1 as well. I was unable to reproduce the error you're seeing. Maybe try disabling the UI plugin you mentioned, to see what happens. This might be something you'll want to report to Jetbrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known issue on macOS https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206887

Workaround:

> Either switch to JDK 8 https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under or run `defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool Yes` in the terminal.